# yacc parser produces unexpected characters. too strange

Tags: compilation, yacc, lex

First I attach the grammar and lexical file here for reference:

grammar.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
extern int yylineno;
int yylex ();
int yyerror ();
//extern char* yytext;

%}

%union{
    int integer;
    float flt;
    char *str;
}

%token <str> IDENTIFIER 
%token <flt> CONSTANTF
%token <integer> CONSTANTI
%token LEFT_BRACKET RIGHT_BRACKET
%token EQ INC_OP DEC_OP LE_OP GE_OP EQ_OP NE_OP

%token SUB_ASSIGN MUL_ASSIGN ADD_ASSIGN
%token TYPE_NAME
%token INT FLOAT VOID
%token IF ELSE WHILE RETURN FOR
%start program
%%

primary_expression
: IDENTIFIER    {printf("use identifier: %s, length is %d\n", $1, strlen($1));}
| CONSTANTI     {printf("use constant Int: %d\n", $1);}
| CONSTANTF     {printf("use constant Float: %f\n", $1);}
| LEFT_BRACKET expression RIGHT_BRACKET
| IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACKET RIGHT_BRACKET {printf("non-param methodCall identifier is: %s\n", $1);}
| IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACKET argument_expression_list RIGHT_BRACKET    {printf("param methodCall identifier is: %s\n", $1);}
| IDENTIFIER INC_OP
| IDENTIFIER DEC_OP
;

postfix_expression
: primary_expression
| postfix_expression '[' expression ']'
;

argument_expression_list
: expression
| argument_expression_list ',' expression
;

unary_expression
: postfix_expression
| INC_OP unary_expression
| DEC_OP unary_expression
| unary_operator unary_expression
;

unary_operator
: '-'
;

multiplicative_expression
: unary_expression
| multiplicative_expression '*' unary_expression
| multiplicative_expression '/' unary_expression
;

additive_expression
: multiplicative_expression
| additive_expression '+' multiplicative_expression
| additive_expression '-' multiplicative_expression
;

comparison_expression
: additive_expression
| additive_expression '<' additive_expression
| additive_expression '>' additive_expression
| additive_expression LE_OP additive_expression
| additive_expression GE_OP additive_expression
| additive_expression EQ_OP additive_expression
| additive_expression NE_OP additive_expression
;

expression
: unary_expression assignment_operator comparison_expression
| comparison_expression
;

assignment_operator
: EQ
| MUL_ASSIGN
| ADD_ASSIGN
| SUB_ASSIGN
;

declaration
: type_name declarator_list ';'
;

declarator_list
: declarator
| declarator_list ',' declarator
;

type_name
: VOID  
| INT   
| FLOAT
;

declarator
: IDENTIFIER    {printf("declare an identifer: %s\n",$1);}
| LEFT_BRACKET declarator RIGHT_BRACKET
| declarator '[' CONSTANTI ']'
| declarator '[' ']'
| declarator LEFT_BRACKET parameter_list RIGHT_BRACKET
| declarator LEFT_BRACKET RIGHT_BRACKET
;

parameter_list
: parameter_declaration
| parameter_list ',' parameter_declaration
;

parameter_declaration
: type_name declarator
;

statement
: compound_statement
| expression_statement 
| selection_statement
| iteration_statement
| jump_statement
;

compound_statement
: '{' '}'
| '{' statement_list '}'
| '{' declaration_list statement_list '}'
;

declaration_list
: declaration
| declaration_list declaration
;

statement_list
: statement
| statement_list statement
;

expression_statement
: ';'
| expression ';'
;

selection_statement
: IF '(' expression ')' statement
| IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement
| FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression ')' statement
;

iteration_statement
: WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
;

jump_statement
: RETURN ';'
| RETURN expression ';'
;

program
: external_declaration
| program external_declaration
;

external_declaration
: function_definition
| declaration
;

function_definition
: type_name declarator compound_statement
;

%%
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char yytext[];
extern int column;
extern int yylineno;
extern FILE *yyin;

char *file_name = NULL;

int yyerror (char *s) {
    fflush (stdout);
    fprintf (stderr, "%s:%d:%d: %s\n", file_name, yylineno, column, s);
    return 0;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *input = NULL;
    if (argc==2) {
    input = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    file_name = strdup (argv[1]);
    if (input) {
        yyin = input;
    }
    else {
      fprintf (stderr, "%s: Could not open %s\n", *argv, argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    }
    else {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s: error: no input file\n", *argv);
    return 1;
    }
    yyparse ();
    free (file_name);
    return 0;
}
```

scanner.l

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "grammar.tab.h"
void count();
int comment ();
int check_type ();
%}
D[0-9]
L[a-zA-Z_]
%option yylineno
%%
"/*"        { comment(); }
"//".*          { count(); }
"float"     { count(); return(FLOAT); }
"if"        { count(); return(IF); }
"else"      { count(); return(ELSE); }
"int"       { count(); return(INT); }
"return"    { count(); return(RETURN); }
"void"      { count(); return(VOID); }
"while"     { count(); return(WHILE); }
"for"       { count(); return(FOR); }
[$]?{L}({L}|{D})*   { count(); yylval.str=yytext; return(IDENTIFIER); printf("recognize identifier");}
{D}+        { count(); yylval.integer=atoi(yytext); return(CONSTANTI); }
{D}+"."{D}*     { count(); yylval.flt=atof(yytext); return(CONSTANTF); }
"("         {count();return(LEFT_BRACKET);}
")"         {count();return(RIGHT_BRACKET);}
"="         {count();return(EQ);}
"+="        { count(); return(ADD_ASSIGN); }
"-="        { count(); return(SUB_ASSIGN); }
"*="        { count(); return(MUL_ASSIGN); }
"++"        { count(); return(INC_OP); }
"--"        { count(); return(DEC_OP); }
"<="        { count(); return(LE_OP); }
">="        { count(); return(GE_OP); }
"=="        { count(); return(EQ_OP); }
"!="        { count(); return(NE_OP); }
";"     { count(); return(';'); }
"{"         { count(); return('{'); }
"}"         { count(); return('}'); }
","     { count(); return(','); }
"/"     { count(); return('/'); }
"["         { count(); return('['); }
"]"         { count(); return(']'); }
"."     { count(); return('.'); }
"!"     { count(); return('!'); }
"-"     { count(); return('-'); }
"+"     { count(); return('+'); }
"*"     { count(); return('*'); }
"<"     { count(); return('<'); }
">"     { count(); return('>'); }
[ \t\v\n\f] { count(); }
.       { /* ignore bad characters */ }

%%
int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}

int comment() {
    char c, c1;

loop:
    while ((c = input()) != '*' && c != 0);
    if ((c1 = input()) != '/' && c != 0) {
        unput(c1);
        goto loop;
    }
    return 0;
}

int column = 0;

void count() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; yytext[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (yytext[i] == '\n')
            column = 0;
        else if (yytext[i] == '\t')
            column += 8 - (column % 8);
        else
            column++;
    }
}
```

And the Makefile:

```
LEX=lex
YACC=yacc
CFLAGS=-Wall
CC=gcc

all:parse

parse:grammar.c scanner.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

grammar.c:grammar.y
    $(YACC) -d -o $@ --defines=grammar.tab.h $^

%.c:%.l
    $(LEX) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f grammar.c scanner.c
```

==============================================================================

The problem is that:
When I parse an input file like:

```
int a;
int fhu;
float fs;

int drive(float te){
    int b;
    b=1;
    fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
declare an identifer: a
declare an identifer: fhu
declare an identifer: fs
declare an identifer: drive
declare an identifer: te
declare an identifer: b
use identifier: b=, length is 2
use constant Int: 1
use identifier: fhu =, length is 5
use identifier: fs), length is 3
param methodCall identifier is: drive(fs)
use identifier: fs =, length is 4
use constant Float: 0.400000
use constant Int: 0
```

I got quite confused that why "b=","fhu =", "fs)" are recognized with the unexpected character '=', ' =', and ')'. You can see that in the declaration statements, identifiers are correctly recognized, but not in the primary statements.

Why they use the same lexical rules but produce different results?

Is there anyone could help me on this problem? I am new to yacc and any suggestions may be helpful and welcomed! Please, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Also, please read up on how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
The grammar doesn't compile on Mac OS X 10.9.1: `grammar.y:46.3-14: symbol expressionfs is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules`. Please reduce the grammar so it contains the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem. Offhand, I suspect the problem is to do with storing (or not storing) copies of the string returned by the lexical scanner, but I've not read everything yet.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your responding. Actually the symbol expressionfs should be expression. I may made a mistake when copying the grammar.y. I just corrected the symbol and now it should compiler on your machine(It complies well on my Ubuntu_12.04 machine). For your suspect, how did you come up with the idea of storing?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Very nice recommendation for that excellent article. I will try to follow the principles proposed in that article in my questions in the future. For this question, the grammar file may be better to be complete. It compiles well when no actions are added in the grammar.y. Here I just add the printf action to get the recognized identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in my first comment, the problem is related to not storing a copy of the string returned by the lexical scanner.  I was able to reproduce the problem pretty much as described (working on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks rather than Ubuntu, so it isn't platform specific).

The 'trivial' fix is:

```
[$]?{L}({L}|{D})*   { count(); yylval.str=strdup(yytext); printf("recognize identifier (%s)\n", yylval.str); return(IDENTIFIER);}
```

Three changes in there:

1. Move the `printf()` before the return so it is executed.
2. Have the `printf()` print the identifier string.
3. The critical one: use `strdup()` to make a copy of the string!

The word 'trivial' is in quotes (twice) because the immediate issue with allocating memory is 'where is it released' and the current answer is 'nowhere — until the program exits', and that is unlikely to be a suitable long-term solution.  So, you will need to review how you use the identifiers returned by the IDENTIFIER token type, ensuring that the memory is released.  But this will get you back on track.

Output from running `parse` on your sample file:

```
recognize identifier (a)
declare an identifer: a
recognize identifier (fhu)
declare an identifer: fhu
recognize identifier (fs)
declare an identifer: fs
recognize identifier (drive)
declare an identifer: drive
recognize identifier (te)
declare an identifer: te
recognize identifier (b)
declare an identifer: b
recognize identifier (b)
use identifier: b, length is 1
use constant Int: 1
recognize identifier (fhu)
use identifier: fhu, length is 3
recognize identifier (drive)
recognize identifier (fs)
use identifier: fs, length is 2
param methodCall identifier is: drive
recognize identifier (fs)
use identifier: fs, length is 2
use constant Float: 0.400000
use constant Int: 0
```

---

> The last thing I want to know is why, when the code directly assigns `yytext` to `yylval.str`, does the grammar parser get "`b=`" rather than "`b`"? How does `yytext` change when doing the grammar parsing?

Try the following addition to your code — specifically, the functions `push_identifier()` and `dump_identifiers()` in `grammary.y` — and use both the 'with `strdup()`' and 'without `strdup()`' versions of `scanner.l`.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
extern int yylineno;
int yylex(void);
int yyerror(char *str);
static void push_identifier(char *str);
//extern char* yytext;

%}

%expect 1
%union{
    int integer;
    float flt;
    char *str;
}

%token <str> IDENTIFIER 
%token <flt> CONSTANTF
%token <integer> CONSTANTI
%token LEFT_BRACKET RIGHT_BRACKET
%token EQ INC_OP DEC_OP LE_OP GE_OP EQ_OP NE_OP

%token SUB_ASSIGN MUL_ASSIGN ADD_ASSIGN
%token TYPE_NAME
%token INT FLOAT VOID
%token IF ELSE WHILE RETURN FOR
%start program

%%

primary_expression
    : IDENTIFIER    {printf("use identifier: %s, length is %zu\n", $1, strlen($1)); push_identifier($1);}
    | CONSTANTI     {printf("use constant Int: %d\n", $1);}
    | CONSTANTF     {printf("use constant Float: %f\n", $1);}
    | LEFT_BRACKET expression RIGHT_BRACKET
    | IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACKET RIGHT_BRACKET {printf("non-param methodCall identifier is: %s\n", $1); push_identifier($1);}
    | IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACKET argument_expression_list RIGHT_BRACKET    {printf("param methodCall identifier is: %s\n", $1); push_identifier($1);}
    | IDENTIFIER INC_OP { push_identifier($1); }
    | IDENTIFIER DEC_OP { push_identifier($1); }
    ;

postfix_expression
    : primary_expression
    | postfix_expression '[' expression ']'
    ;

argument_expression_list
    : expression
    | argument_expression_list ',' expression
    ;

unary_expression
    : postfix_expression
    | INC_OP unary_expression
    | DEC_OP unary_expression
    | unary_operator unary_expression
    ;

unary_operator
    : '-'
    ;

multiplicative_expression
    : unary_expression
    | multiplicative_expression '*' unary_expression
    | multiplicative_expression '/' unary_expression
    ;

additive_expression
    : multiplicative_expression
    | additive_expression '+' multiplicative_expression
    | additive_expression '-' multiplicative_expression
    ;

comparison_expression
    : additive_expression
    | additive_expression '<' additive_expression
    | additive_expression '>' additive_expression
    | additive_expression LE_OP additive_expression
    | additive_expression GE_OP additive_expression
    | additive_expression EQ_OP additive_expression
    | additive_expression NE_OP additive_expression
    ;

expression
    : unary_expression assignment_operator comparison_expression
    | comparison_expression
    ;

assignment_operator
    : EQ
    | MUL_ASSIGN
    | ADD_ASSIGN
    | SUB_ASSIGN
    ;

declaration
    : type_name declarator_list ';'
    ;

declarator_list
    : declarator
    | declarator_list ',' declarator
    ;

type_name
    : VOID  
    | INT   
    | FLOAT
    ;

declarator
    : IDENTIFIER    {printf("declare an identifer: %s\n",$1); push_identifier($1); }
    | LEFT_BRACKET declarator RIGHT_BRACKET
    | declarator '[' CONSTANTI ']'
    | declarator '[' ']'
    | declarator LEFT_BRACKET parameter_list RIGHT_BRACKET
    | declarator LEFT_BRACKET RIGHT_BRACKET
    ;

parameter_list
    : parameter_declaration
    | parameter_list ',' parameter_declaration
    ;

parameter_declaration
    : type_name declarator
    ;

statement
    : compound_statement
    | expression_statement 
    | selection_statement
    | iteration_statement
    | jump_statement
    ;

compound_statement
    : '{' '}'
    | '{' statement_list '}'
    | '{' declaration_list statement_list '}'
    ;

declaration_list
    : declaration
    | declaration_list declaration
    ;

statement_list
    : statement
    | statement_list statement
    ;

expression_statement
    : ';'
    | expression ';'
    ;

selection_statement
    : IF '(' expression ')' statement
    | IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement
    | FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression ')' statement
    ;

iteration_statement
    : WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
    ;

jump_statement
    : RETURN ';'
    | RETURN expression ';'
    ;

program
    : external_declaration
    | program external_declaration
    ;

external_declaration
    : function_definition
    | declaration
    ;

function_definition
    : type_name declarator compound_statement
    ;

%%

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char yytext[];
extern int column;
extern int yylineno;
extern FILE *yyin;

char *file_name = NULL;

int yyerror(char *s)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d:%d: %s\n", file_name, yylineno, column, s);
    return 0;
}

static char *list[20];
static int   sp = 0;
static void push_identifier(char *str)
{
    list[sp++] = str;  // Appalling lack of error checking - not fit for production
}

static void dump_identifiers(void)
{
    printf("Identifiers (%d):\n", sp);
    for (int i = 0; i < sp; i++)
        printf("[%2d] = <<%s>>\n", i, list[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input = NULL;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        file_name = strdup(argv[1]);
        if (input)
        {
            yyin = input;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Could not open %s\n", *argv, argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error: no input file\n", *argv);
        return 1;
    }
    yyparse();
    dump_identifiers();
    free(file_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Using the 'with `strdup()`' version, the output ends:

```
use constant Int: 0
Identifiers (11):
[ 0] = <<a>>
[ 1] = <<fhu>>
[ 2] = <<fs>>
[ 3] = <<drive>>
[ 4] = <<te>>
[ 5] = <<b>>
[ 6] = <<b>>
[ 7] = <<fhu>>
[ 8] = <<fs>>
[ 9] = <<drive>>
[10] = <<fs>>
```

Using the 'without `strdup()`' version, the output ends:

```
use constant Int: 0
Identifiers (11):
[ 0] = <<a;
int fhu;
float fs;

int drive(float te){
    int b;
    b=1;
    fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 1] = <<fhu;
float fs;

int drive(float te){
    int b;
    b=1;
    fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 2] = <<fs;

int drive(float te){
    int b;
    b=1;
    fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 3] = <<drive(float te){
    int b;
    b=1;
    fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 4] = <<te){
    int b;
    b=1;
    fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 5] = <<b;
    b=1;
    fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 6] = <<b=1;
    fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 7] = <<fhu = drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 8] = <<fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[ 9] = <<drive(fs);
    fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
[10] = <<fs = 0.4;
    return 0;
}
>>
```

In other words, the code in the scanner is reusing the buffer that `yytext` points to for its own purposes.  This is what happens at the end; I'm not sure what is going on while the code is being parsed — you'd need to include a call to `dump_identifiers()` every time `push_identifier()` is called.  Printing addresses in `push_identifier()` and in `dump_identifiers()` might also be illuminating.

Comment: Ah, it does solve the problem! Thanks for reminding of the use of strdup on the issue of memory allocation. The last thing I want to know is that, when directly assign yytext to yylval.str, why the grammar parser gets "b=" rather than "b"? How yytext changes when do the grammar parsing?

Comment: @qingl97: `yytext` is the internal buffer flex uses to look for token, so it is modified by each call to `yylex`.  That's why you need to make a copy, rather than just returning it directly in `yylval` -- the latter gives you a pointer into a buffer that will change as more tokens are recognized.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Just as what Jonathan Leffler added in the answer above, I can see well what you said. But still need some time to digest this issue. I am so glad to receive both of your so kind and useful help for my first question at Stackoverflow. Quite motivating and illuminating! It's really a great place for learning and sharing!